# ASP.NET - how to automatically refresh element's value for multiple users

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am real ASP.Net beginner and I could use advice from someone wiser than me to give me direction where to look and what to learn.

I am working on ASP.Net/C# webapp for our dept (target .Net is 4.8).

In short: **I need to update page for multiple users every time certain value changes in the code behind and do it as fast as possible**

Long: There is mandatory feature I can't bypass. Situation: 50 users will be on the same aspx page, watching it. There will be field with certain value. (it can be text field or whatever element will help me to achieve this). Admins can change the value of this element by clicking one of the related buttons. If such event happens, it is absolutely crucial to reflect this change in all of the browsers simultaneously and as fast as possible. Miliseconds matters. (not my idea)

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Please excuse me if my question is too silly. I am not expecting some sample/solution code on such badly formulated question, just general direction where to look (what to learn) as I could not find any solution so far. There should be something since it kind of resembles auction system, you bid, others see it immediatelly and can take action.

thank you in advance

Comment: Consider using signalr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case seems to fit well with the usage of signal-r.

Basically you need something which allows you to set a bidirectional communication between the client and the server, so that you are able to broadcast a message from the server to all the connected clients whenever something important happens on the server.

You can start from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/). This topic is broad, so you need to first of all read the docs and play with some of the provided sample applications. The advantage of this framework for real time web applications is that it fits really well in the ASP.NET and ASP.NET core ecosystem.

Avoid any solution based on client polling of the server state, by doing so you will basically ddos yourself. A push-based solution (like the one offered by signal-r) is way more efficient.

Comment: Thanks!!! That seems to be exactly what I was looking for! I was thinking about workaround but it would do exactly what you accurately called "ddos myself". Thanks again.

Comment: P.S. I upvoted the answer but don't have enough points yet! Started reading docs and it is just perfect, you made my day.